# Oreo - Communication between custom activity and native daemon

Tags: android, android-8.1-oreo

I Need some help with system architecture design specific to Android Oreo.

For Android Nougat, I had an activity talk to a native daemon (designed in C) through sockets. Both the activity and the native daemon were designed by me.

From the docs on Android Oreo, it looks like the socket communication between two processes is now deprecated.
I tried finding for alternatives online, but the information seems limited. Any help on this subject would be greatly appreciated.